# Handling erroneous user input such as float and number length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to handle a user's  erroneous input such as floats and integers of length inferior to say 4 and superior to 4 so that whenever it happens, I ask the user to re-enter the 4 digits number.

**The expected outcome.**

```
>>> beginning = input('Enter date: ')
>>> Enter date: 1985.0
>>> Please give a four digit integer for date.
>>> Enter date: 19.8
>>> Please give a four digit integer for date.
>>> Enter date: blabla
>>> Please give a four digit integer for date.
>>> Enter date: 200
>>> Please give a four digit integer for date.
>>> Enter date: 20000
>>> Please give a four digit integer for date.
>>> Enter date: 1980
>>> # This is good
```

**Here's my attempt.**

```
def reading_ans():
    while True:
        try:
            ans = input('Enter date: ')
        if float(ans) != float(int(float((ans)))):
            print("Please give a four digit integer for date.")
        elif len(ans) != 4:
            print("Please give a four digit integer for date.")
        else:
            return ans
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Well, my function isn't doing as the expected outcome.

Comment: That's because `ValueError` will never be raised. Why do you think `ValueError` would be raised in your code?

Comment: Ok. I changed the code. The function is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that your condition use the fact that `ans.isdigit()` is only `True` if `ans` consists solely of digits.

```
def reading_ans():
    while True:
        ans = input('Enter date: ')
        if len(ans) == 4 and ans.isdigit():
            return ans
        print("Please give a four digit integer for date.")
```